# Android - ActionBar item - onClickListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

I'm trying to implement onClickListener for the item which is a submenu of the ActionBar. Whatever I'm trying to do the result is the same - "Unfortunatelly, application has stopped." However there are no errors during compilation. All seems to be ok, but it is't. What goes wrong here? Thanks for help.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        View view = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.delete).getActionView();
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Execute when actionbar's item is touched
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

And here is the main.xml file where ActionBar and its item is created

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
        <menu>
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/delete" 
                android:title="@string/delete" 
                android:showAsAction="always" 
                android:orderInCategory="200"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: onoptionitemselect() call this method and do it if(item.getid()==R.id.delete)....

Comment: thanks a lot peter, onoptionitemselect() method works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`getActionView()` returns a valid object (not `null`) only you have a custom action view (with [setActionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29))